# How to remove an uploaded character from Mixamo

Tags: unity-game-engine, mixamo

How do you actually clear/remove an uploaded character on Mixamo? I don't want to upload a new character but rather just remove this one and see the default xbots. Is there a way?

I have searched on this topic but don't see anyone else asking the same thing. It's not intuitive.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can click on the character tab and select one of the default ones, including the default bots. Cheers!

Stefano - founder of Mixamo

[mixamo UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMSd1.png)